# Calling sudo from a script on user login

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

#### Scenario:

Upon login over standard graphical login screen in a Linux based operating system, I would like to run automatically a script. This script makes some system calls for which it requires root privileges. To be more specific, in my Fedora 19 box I would like to run a script that after my login asks me for a root password to run cryptsetup and mount utilities to unlock and mount a LUKS-ecrypted partition (and a LUKS password as well).

#### Example:

Here is an example of a simple script, let's say *luks.sh* that I save into */home/<user>/* directory. To obtain a password from a script using a visual component I use `yad`.

```
#!/bin/bash
STYLE="--text-align=center --borders=15 --center --sticky --on-top --width=400"
TITLE="Input root password"
password=$(yad $STYLE --entry --title="$TITLE" --text="$TITLE." --hide-text)

# Make a call to test "sudo". If it is sucessful, subsequent sudo calls won't
# require a password anymore):

err=$(echo $password | sudo -S -- echo "" 2>&1)
yad --notebook $STYLE --title="Sudo output" --text "Exit code: $?, Msg: $err"
```

#### Problem:

I would like the script above after login. I tried several options:

- Adding `bash luks.sh` at the end of my */home/<user>/.bash_profile*
- Adding `bash luks.sh &` at the end of my */home/<user>/.bash_profile*
- Adding `sleep 30 && bash luks.sh &` at the end of my */home/<user>/.bash_profile*
- The same as above and trying to check for sudo in a loop for 30s.
- Adding all of the above into *System/Preferences/Startup Appliacations*

Every time I got an error: `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`. For some reason, no matter where I place the execution of this script it never has tty. One solution would be modifying the *requiretty* option in */etc/sudoers*. But that is a security threat and I cannot go this way (see section *motivation* below).

So my question is: **Is there any way to run a script with sudo after login in a way, that would not require lowering security restrictions?**

#### Motivation:

I need to unlock and mount the partition after boot, so I can also perform wake-on-lan and remote ssh access (which I can't when the boot gets stuck on waiting for the LUKS password). Unlocking the partition manually every time I login is not comfortable enough and I would like to simplify it to *Boot* -> *Login* -> *Get asked for root and LUKS password automatically* -> *Get LUKS partition unlocked and mounted*. I cannot lower security restrictions because I need this for several work computers. It has to run under a user that has a password and it is always required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to try gksudo. I don't know if gksudo requires a terminal or not, but using gksudo would be cleaner than obtaining input through yad and manually feeding it to sudo. It should also take the same command line arguments

Comment: Thanks for the tip. There is no `gksudo` in Fedora. However, there is `beesu` and it works for the script above! I don't have the original script with me right now to try it but so far it seems you solved my problem :-).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you will not solve this problem by simply trying to override 'requiretty' option without disabling it first. Of course disabling it completely is not a very good idea, so you have to selectively disable it for a particular entity. You can, for example, create a specific group and then add an exception into /etc/sudoers below the general default setting:

```
Defaults requiretty
Defaults:%notty !requiretty
```

This will remove 'requiretty' restriction for 'notty' group.

Comment: could "ssh -t" suffice here?